# Refresh token handling using retrofit in android java

Tags: java, android, authentication, retrofit2, refresh-token

i am using jwt Authentication in android . i am able to get access token and expire time and using interceptors i am sending in headers . here everything works fine . but when token expires  i am not able to handle the case.

i am using single ton retrofit class and i have the refresh token api .   but i don't  know how to call the refresh token api  when the token expires .

i  have 2  suggestions

i have to call the refresh token api before the access token expires or else whenever the 401 error occurs  it should automatically  call the refresh token api

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: how to handle the refresh token when the access token expires  using retrofit ?